# By default getting random value in password filled in ios, and working fine in android in react-native

Tags: react-native

The password field in the app gets filled with random data. This only occurs in iOS without entering any value, this does not occur on android in react-native.

I am using the following input:

```
<TextInput onChangeText={this.handlePassword} secureTextEntry={this.state.showpassword} style={styles.textinputStyle} value={this.state.password} placeholder="Password" placeholderTextColor={colors.white} />
```

Answer (score 0):

iOS automatically generates a password for the user if it recognizes a password input field. More details can be found in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill?language=objc).

Comment: Thanks for this information, but in the password field, it generates a random single value, not a password, So how did I remove this in ios + react-native.

Comment: Like a number? Could you add the code that builds the input? @nltiwari

Comment: A number like sometimes 1, sometimes 2 and so on...
TextInput code?

Comment: TextInput
                  onChangeText={this.handlePassword}
                  secureTextEntry={this.state.showpassword}
                  style={styles.textinputStyle}
                  value={this.state.password}
                  placeholder="Password"
                  placeholderTextColor={colors.white}
                />

Comment: Does it occur if you replace  `value={this.state.password}` by `value=''`? @nltiwari

Comment: No, at that time it will not, and I found from where this issue occurs.
Actually I am using react-native-keychain and from this, in ios, it will not clear the data in the stored keychain, so that's why it comes random value occurs.